# ¿Cómo se leen los precios?

Tags: números

Esta mañana oyendo las noticias, comentaban algo sobre una compañía que tenía las acciones a "veintisiete con ochenta y cuatro dólares" (no recuerdo la cantidad exacta), y me surgió la duda.

Por ejemplo, ¿cómo se leería "19,95 €"?

- Diecinueve coma noventa y cinco euros
- Diecinueve con noventa y cinco euros
- Diecinueve euros con noventa y cinco
- Diecinueve noventa y cinco

No le pongo moneda a la última fórmula porque nunca la he oído con moneda, pero sí de manera habitual tal cual la he puesto, pronunciando solo las cantidades sin ningún elemento que haga de nexo.

¿Cuál es la correcta? ¿Qué otras opciones correctas hay aparte de esa?

Comment: Relacionado: [How to read a decimal number in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4159/1674)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo diría que los precios, al ser números decimales, siguen la misma regla que estos, por lo que aplicaría la respuesta a [How to read a decimal number in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4159/12637). Sin embargo, echo en falta allí lo que dice la RAE al respecto, que es [lo siguiente](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UMRQsgKNRSbdyazz):

> Cuando los números se expresan con palabras, debe mencionarse primer la parte entera y después la decimal, unidas ambas por la conjunción *y* o por la preposición *con*. Así, el número 20,58 [...] corresponde a la expresión *veinte (unidades o enteros) y cincuenta y ocho (centésimas)*.

Siguiendo esta norma, las formas válidas de expresar ese mismo número si fuera un precio serían (usando las unidades españolas):

- Veinte euros y cincuenta y ocho céntimos.
- Veinte euros con cincuenta y ocho céntimos.

En todo caso, al entenderse que al hablar de un precio las unidades están claras según el país que corresponda, valdría también:

- Veinte con cincuenta y ocho.

No me suena bien "veinte y cincuenta y ocho" en este caso. Continúa la *Ortografía*:

> [...] es también habitual leer simplemente la secuencia de signos de que se componen; así, no es infrecuente formular oralmente el decimal 2,5 o 2.5 como *dos coma cinco* o *dos punto cinco*; y 7,08 o 7.08 como *siete coma cero ocho* o *siete punto cero ocho*.

Esto me parece más propio del ámbito científico más que del económico. No recuerdo haber oído a nadie decir *siete coma cero ocho euros*, sino *siete [euros] con ocho* a lo sumo (y todavía a veces mi mente piensa que *siete con ocho* son *siete euros y ochenta céntimos*). Pero sí, también sería válido decir *diecinueve coma noventa y cinco euros* o *diecinueve punto noventa y cinco* según el país.

Con respecto a tu última propuesta, me recuerda un poco a esa costumbre de comerse algunas preposiciones, como en "ponme un bocata mortadela". En este caso sería una omisión de la preposición *con* en *diecinueve noventa y cinco*, aunque si te fijas no valdría para números grandes: *mil novecientos noventa y nueve noventa y cinco* suena un tanto caótico si no especificas dónde está la separación decimal.

Comment: "Veinte con cincuenta y ocho"  es el que mejor me suena para Colombia aunque en nuestra economía los centavos no se usan desde hace un siglo y esos 20.58€ son setenta y cinco mil quinientos veinte pesos. :-)

Comment: Todas las expresiones son correctas, hay que tener en cuenta que el caracter para indicar decimales varía entre países, por ejemplo en México usan el punto, en otros países usan la coma; además con la predominancia de sistemas de información creados por empresas en Estados Unidos es habitual el punto.

Comment: Si bien en Colombia físicamente dejaron de usarse monedas para centavos (existieron la de 1, 5 10, y 50 centavos) aproximadamente entre 1975 y 1980, lo curioso (y hasta absurdo) es que existen bancos que si usan centavos en sus sistemas de información para la gestión de créditos y tarjetas de crédito.